# Is it possible to add a separator to MvcSiteMap menu node?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'd like to be able to add a separator bar in my menu which is created using MvcSiteMap library.

The mvcSiteMapNodes resolve to `<li></li>` items with the action method inside.
However, I would like just a dummy `<li class="divider"></li>` node which renders a divider item in my menu.

e.g.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Admin" url="#admin" roles="Admin">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit Users" controller="User" action="Users" roles="Admin" />      
  <mvcSiteMapNode class="divider"  />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="User Audit" controller="User" action="Audit" roles="Admin" />      
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to put the separator sitemap node in your xml sitemap file and set the clickable attribute to false. If it wants a controller and/or action then make one up specifically for a separator.

Then create your own templates for rendering the menu. Within the templates you can examine the node model and put what ever html attributes you want in the rendered result. So if the sitemap node clickable attribute is false you can insert a string in the html class attribute and have your css style it however you like.

See the "Customizing rendered output" section at this url : https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/HtmlHelper-functions

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>

<% if (Model.IsCurrentNode && Model.SourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString() != "MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper")  { %>
    <%=Model.Title %>
<% } else if (Model.IsClickable) { %>
<a href="<%=Model.Url %>"><%=Model.Title %></a>
<% } else { %>
<%=Model.Title %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The MvcSiteMap supports a 'clickable' attribute on mvcSiteMapNode which can render an empty

```
<li> </li>
```

but can't see a way to specify the class and it seems to require a valid controller and action!

If that's no good then JQuery could do it for you....

Given this html:-

```
<div id="sitemap">
  <ul>
    <li>Edit Users</li>
    <li>User Audit</li>
    <li>Another Option</li>
    <li>Something else</li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

and this JQuery call:-

```
$('<li class="divider"></li>').appendTo('div#sitemap li:not(:last)');
```

you should get your required output.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNgfQ/4/) to show it working.

**UPDATE**

Ok here's an updated solution to insert the divider at your required location:-

```
$('div#sitemap li').last().prev().after('<li class="divider"></li>');

$('<li class="divider"></li>').appendTo('div#sitemap li:nth-child(3)');

$('div#sitemap li:last').prev().after('<li class="divider"></li>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNgfQ/5/) updated to show all of these

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it looks like a divider is being created on every item. I need the divider to be specifically placed in a list. Think of the Help menu in windows apps. The 'about' item is often separated from the rest by a divider.

Comment: I see, didn't realise that. I have updated the answer and the JSFiddle  with 3 methods to get the divider to display before the last item.

Comment: ok thanks, would be nice if I could specify the position in the mvcsitemap file somehow, maybe a dummy one which specifies a dummy controller/action which then is replaced by the divider. Maybe I'm asking too much! The other option is to add the feature to MvcSiteMap itself;)

Comment: Yeah adding the feature yourself is one option. If you are happy to have the dummy controller/action then you can change the display templates to look for the dummy one and render the code you want:-

<mvcSiteMapNode title="divider/dummy/whatever"  />

Comment: and then in MenuHelperModel.cshtml I changed the code to check the title

@foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) {
        if (node.Title == "divider")
         { 
            <li class="divider">&nbsp;</li>
         }
         else
         {
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)</li>
         }
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you set the title as "Separator" and clickable to "false" the node will appear as a line

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Separator" clickable="false" />
```